# Sequelize get sum of colum - TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined

Tags: sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

I'm using NodeJs, Expressjs and Sequelize for my project.

My code is:

```
static report() {
    return AgencyEventReportTable.findAll({
        attributes: [
            'agency_id',
            'user_id'
            [
                AgencyEventReportTable.sum('total_selled'),
                'total'
            ]

        ],
        group: ['user_id', 'agency_id']
    })
}
```

The error I'm getting when I use Model.sum in Sequelize:

```
Unhandled rejection TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined
at attributes.map.attr (/home/node-server/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query-generator.js:1412:22)
at MySQLQueryGenerator.selectQuery (/home/node-server/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query-generator.js:1156:28)
at QueryInterface.select (/home/node-server/node_modules/sequelize/lib/query-interface.js:1119:27)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `AgencyEventReportTable.sum` it like that, try this :

```
AgencyEventReportTable.findAll({
        attributes: [
            'agency_id',
            'user_id'
            [
                sequelize.fn('sum', sequelize.col('total_selled'))
                'total'
            ]

        ],
        group: ['user_id', 'agency_id']
})
```

Comment: I tried this way. It not working and has the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're missing a comma after `'user_id'` (on line 5)